# Equivalence Rules Proofs

Tags: relations, equivalence-relations, proof-theory, relation-algebra

I've been reading about the relational algebra equivalence rules as we see them  [Here](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/attachment/32513/EquivalenceRules.pdf) or [Here](http://www.mathpath.org/proof/proof.inference.htm) and also I have been looking for proofs of those rules everywhere. I see there are some ways such as truth table or diagrams to show the equalities but I was wondering if anyone's aware of a robust mathematical way to prove those rule equalities?

I started reading and it led me to the De Morgan forth paper "On the logic of relations, 1860" as he says

> we must know and use
>   the properties * A is B gives B is A' and ' A is B and B is C, compounded, give A is C *

which is an understandable basic logic but I'm just wondering if there is any way to prove those equivalence rules by mathematics?

I appreciate any help here.

Comment: From your references I see that you are confusing different mathematical notions. State clearly proofs of what rules you are seeking.

Answer (score 1):

The truth-table method is a perfectly robust method to do this. The equivalence of two statements in propositional logic means that in every scenario, the two statements have the same truth-value. Since truth-tables explore all relevant types of scenarios, they do exactly what needs to be done to demonstrate equivalence.